# MVC 5 DropDown Lists

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

So I'm just working on customizing some views with some controls that will allow the users to narrow down the results we would expect on the page, since we're expecting a great deal of information.

My intellisense is broken in VS2015, so I'm stumbling around in the dark a bit.

So I've populated a couple dropdown lists, month and year. Not the prettiest, but it works:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Month", new List<SelectListItem>
           {
                new SelectListItem { Text = "January", Value = "1"},
                new SelectListItem { Text = "February", Value = "2"},
                new SelectListItem { Text = "March", Value = "3"},
                new SelectListItem { Text = "April", Value = "4"},
                new SelectListItem { Text = "May", Value = "5"},
                new SelectListItem { Text = "June", Value = "6"},
                new SelectListItem { Text = "July", Value = "7"},
                new SelectListItem { Text = "August", Value = "8"},
                new SelectListItem { Text = "September", Value = "9"},
                new SelectListItem { Text = "October", Value = "10"},
                new SelectListItem { Text = "November", Value = "11"},
                new SelectListItem { Text = "December", Value = "12"}
           }, "Month")
           @Html.DropDownList("Year", new List<SelectListItem>
            {
                new SelectListItem { Text = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.Year - 1), Value = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.Year - 1)},
                new SelectListItem { Text = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.Year), Value = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.Year), Selected = true},
                new SelectListItem { Text = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.Year + 1), Value = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.Year + 1)},
            }, "Year")
```

Now when one of the dropdowns is changed, I'd like to send the dropdown selection from both controls to my Controller for this view, with the contents of the DD list. From there I can reload the page. The MSDN documentation is unclear, as the only constructor for DropDownList has no parameters, so I'm unclear as to where event driven stuff should go.

Comment: Unclear what you asking - if they are in a form, the selected values will be posted to your controller but what do your mean _with the contents of the DD list_? (and no, its _Not the prettiest_ - its awful). And what _event driven stuff_ are you referring to?

Comment: "and no, its Not the prettiest - its awful" - Thanks for rubbing it in. I'm well aware of how ugly it is at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle this usecase is to keep your SELECT elements inside a `form` and submit it when an the change event happen on the select elements.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index","Home",FormMethod.Get))
{
  <!-- your existing code for SELECT elements goes here-->
}
```

Now you can listen to the `change` event on the SELECT elements and submit the closest form.

```
$(function () {

    $("#Year,#Month").change(function() {
        $(this).closest("form").submit();
     });

});
```

Assuming the `Index` action method accepts the Year and Month as paratmeters

```
public ActionResult Index(int? year,int? month)
{
  // Check the year and month values, if not null, use them to filter your data
  // to do  : Return something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap the elements with form tag (post action).

on serverside create model that has month and year params like:

```
public class MyModel{
    public string Month {get;set;}
    public string Year {get;set;}
}
```

and your html have to be something like:

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.POST, new { id = "MyForm" })) 
    {
       @Html.DropDownList("Month", *your data*, "select month",   new{ onchange = "document.getElementById('MyForm').submit();" })

       @Html.DropDownList("Year", *your data*, "select year",   new{ onchange = "document.getElementById('MyForm').submit();" })

       <input type='submit' value='make the magic' />
    }
```

this line is  bindig a change event of your dropdown, finding your form by id and submitting it.

new{ onchange = "document.getElementById('MyForm').submit();"

Comment: Severside already has a datamodel, how should I handle adding another one to the view?

Comment: with js you can submit any form or few forms...
and you can put any input into another form with unique ID and submit it on change of any input...